# Marshaling const char* const* (inside a struct) to c# from c++

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I'm attempting to marshal a const char* char* from a dll to c#. I can currently successfully return my struct containing the const char* char* and two int variables. The int variables (Count and Score) are in tact but the const char* char* Words reads as garbage.

Here is the struct definition (in the header):

```
struct __declspec(dllexport) Results {
    const char* const* Words;
    unsigned Count;
    unsigned Score;
    void* UserData;
}; 

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) Results TestResults();
}
```

Here's my C#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct Results
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = 
        UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public IntPtr[] Words;
        public int Count;
        public int Score;
    };

    [DllImport("Test.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr TestResults();
```

Finally, my test in Main():

```
    Results LocalResults = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Results>(TestResults());

    Console.WriteLine(LocalResults.Count.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(LocalResults.Score.ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(LocalResults.Words[i]));
    }
```

(EDIT)

Maybe it's something wrong with the data I'm supplying from c++:

```
__declspec(dllexport) Results TestResults() {

    Results r;

    const char* array[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        array[i] = _dict[i].c_str();
    }
    const char** p = array;
    r.Words = p;

    r.Count = 3;
    r.Score = 4;

    return r;
}
```

Comment: It is not an array at all, *string* is the expected type.  If it is too wonky in the native code then use IntPtr, but how you are supposed to marshal it is not obvious.  The only somewhat standard way is to have a single C string that contains multiple zero-terminated strings with two zeros to indicate the end.

Comment: Unfortunately the only way I've been able to get a string back is by using IntPtr. But when the IntPtr is full of char* marshaling isn't obvious, yes. I've never marshaled anything before so I'm grasping at straws. (Edited to continue thought)

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Memory > Memory 1 to look at the IntPtr.  If it looks too messed up to take a stab at it then you do want to talk to the author of this code.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing anything like that under Debug > Windows. I must be in over my head. I'm the author of all of the code but I'm constrained to using this exact struct for a coding challenge.

Comment: This topic is covered in Microsoft's documentation: [Default Marshaling for Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings), see the [Strings Used in Structures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-for-strings#strings-used-in-structures) section.

Comment: Either define your structures in a way that you are able to properly marshal the data (read Microsoft documentation suggested above), or use C++/CLI instead and write your own conversion code. You then have full control on what you do.

Comment: I must be missing something fundamental because I've been staring at those docs for days and haven't come up with a working solution.

Comment: I've edited and added the code that shows how the struct data is supplied. Does anyone see anything wrong there?